# Website won't load

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-ax-2012, nopcommerce

We have a nopCommerce web site and our own plugin. The plugin used to integrate with Dynamics AX 2012. So the way nopCommerce websites are installed are in two steps. First, you install the nopCommerce platform and then install the plugin.

Now, the trouble we are facing is the platform installs ok, but as soon as you install the above plugin the website does not want to load. The queer thing is it works ok on our DEV and UAT environment. Just not on other systems.

To understand what was wrong we enabled Fusion Log. The fusion log has following log.

---

> Attempting to use native image
> C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Web.28b9ef5a#\f1264cb05d9ff03907ce29e5d22137b1\System.Web.Extensions.ni.dll.
>
> Rejecting native image because it failed the security check. The
> assembly's permissions must have changed since the time it was
> ngenned, or it is running with a different security context.
>
> Discarding native image. Rejecting code sharing because a dependent
> assembly did not match the conditional APTCA share mode

---

I am not able to understand what could be the issue. Could you provide any hints why i am getting this and what could be done to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to [`ngen update`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx).

If this does not help, then try to `uninstall` and `install`.

Comment: we did try ngen update, that hasn't helped. We did think about reinstall, however, the fact that it works only on 2 ( 3, works on my machine too) so the client is concerned it's not the framework. if you have any other idea do let us know.